# How do I sort, or order, after a lodash _.countBy?

Tags: javascript, sorting, lodash

I've done lodash `_.countBy` and was returned an object like so...

```
sponsorCounts = { 300051: 2, 300055: 1, 300064: 6 }
```

Now I'd like to do a sort/order by descending value but all the examples I've found involve pushing data into a separate array to sort like so...

```
var sortable = [];
for (var sponsor in sponsorCounts)
     sortable.push([sponsor, sponsorCounts[sponsor]])
     sortable.sort(
         function(a, b) {
              return b[1] - a[1]
         }
     )
```

Which gives me an array... but I want to keep it in that original object so I can get it like...

```
sponsorCounts = { 300064: 6, 300051: 2, 300055: 1  }
```

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1069666/sorting-javascript-object-by-property-value

Comment: Not a duplicate because I want to keep the object, not create a whole new array.

Answer (score 0):

You can't sort javascript objects. They don't guarantee order. You'll have to use something like an array. Sorry!